# Another way to write this code (Accept non-empty string and capitalize)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for another way to write this code in python (accept and non-empty string and capitalize). Any suggestions?

```
def cap_first(input_string):
  result = str(input_string.capitalize())
    if len(result) > 0:
        return result


print cap_first('park')
print cap_first('parK')
print cap_first(' ')
```

Comment: What's wrong with this, in particular?

Comment: Nothing wrong, just wanted to see if we can obtain the same result differently. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script below does the same thing without using capitalize().

```
#script to capitalize the first letter

def cap_first(input_string):
    #result = str(input_string.capitalize())
    input_string = input_string.lower()
    capital = input_string[0].upper()
    result = input_string.replace(input_string[0],capital)
    if len(result) > 0:
        return result


print(cap_first('park'))
print(cap_first('parK'))
print(cap_first('Park in the back.'))
print(cap_first(' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this :

```
def cap_first(input_string):
    if type(input_string) is str and len(input_string) > 0 :
        lo = input_string.lower()
        result = lo[0].upper() + lo[1:]
        return result

print(cap_first('park'))
print(cap_first('parK'))
print(cap_first(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the str() function call.
If the input_string is not a string, capitalize() is not defined.